# Input specific text in form-box with Python 3 and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am writing a code that automatically creates orders for an online store. I am using Python 3 and Selenium with the firefox driver.

```
def change_address(browser,data):
ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Edit")))
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Edit").click()
while True:
    try:
        ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "contactPerson")))
        break
    except:
        browser.find_element_by_link_text("Edit").click()
fill_field_by_name(browser,"contactPerson",unidecode.unidecode(data["Full Name (Billing)"]))
choose_option_from(browser,"#address-main > div.sa-form > div:nth-child(4) > div > select",data["Country Name (Billing)"])
try:
    data["Address 1 (Billing)"] = str(int(float(data["Address 1  (Billing)"])))
except:
    pass
fill_field_by_name(browser,"address",unidecode.unidecode(data["Address 1 (Billing)"]))
try:
    data["Address 2 (Billing)"] = str(int(float(data["Address 2 (Billing)"])))
except:
    pass
fill_field_by_name(browser,"address2",unidecode.unidecode(data["Address 2 (Billing)"]))
fill_field_by_name(browser,"city",unidecode.unidecode(data["City (Billing)"]))
if not choose_option_from(browser,"#address-main > div.sa-form > div.row.sa-form-group.sa-province-group > div > select",data["State Name (Billing)"]):
    try:
        fill_field_by_name(browser,"province",unidecode.unidecode(data["State Name (Billing)"]))
    except:
        pass
```

this is the function where it tells the script to input specific information. My main problem is in the last line

```
    try:
        fill_field_by_name(browser,"province",unidecode.unidecode(data["State Name (Billing)"]))
    except:
        pass
```

What I need is that instead of just passing, that it inputs a specific text, in this case "--Please select--" so that when it doesnt recognize the state, it just selects the "--Please select--" option instead of choosing any, but I am not sure how to do that.

Hopefully someone can give me a hint or guide me through. Thank you!